# Htaccess file rewrite redirects to unintended location

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I had just started a new project and I wanted to remove the .php file extensions from the url. I did that with .htaccess file and this is my code for it.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php
```

This project directory is not in the root htdocs folder (I'm using xampp and all of this is done on localhost) and when I tried it with a few links, it redirects me to another url.

```
<a href="./register">Register</a>
<a href="./login">Login</a>
```

The register link works perfectly and redirects me to "localhost/dir/register" and displays the correct content. However, the login link doesn't work and instead redirects me to "localhost/login" which of course is not what I intended. There is no other code affecting this and it is confusing me as both links are nearly identical but did different stuff. Is there any explanation or solution to this?

I tried renaming the file and url to "log_in.php" and "./log_in" and it works just fine however I would like to keep the "login" as it is easier to type. I also tried moving it out from the original "htdocs/2022/dir" folder into "htdocs/dir" and everything is working fine.

This is my folder structure:

```
03/26/2022  10:16 PM    <DIR>          .
03/26/2022  10:16 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/26/2022  10:16 PM               804 .htaccess
03/26/2022  10:25 PM    <DIR>          .idea
03/26/2022  09:36 PM    <DIR>          assets
03/26/2022  10:23 PM    <DIR>          errors
03/26/2022  10:55 AM               395 index.php
03/26/2022  10:31 AM                22 login.php
03/26/2022  10:31 AM                23 register.php
               4 File(s)          1,244 bytes
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have another rewrite rule in force ? (or does your login.php itself have some sort of redirection ?)

Comment: Nope I just started this project and the login file just contains a ```echo "Hello"``` and there is no other code in the htaccess file

Comment: What is your file structure? Do you also have a directory called `login`? Where is your .htaccess file?

Comment: I edited the question to show the folder structure. I don't have a directory called ```login```

Comment: "instead redirects me to `localhost/login`" - do you actually see an external 3xx redirect? ie. You are requesting `http://localhost/dir/login` (as confirmed by the browser HTTP request), but the _server_ is redirecting you to `/login`? What is the HTTP response code of the redirect response? There is nothing in what you've posted that could trigger a redirect. "and redirects me to `localhost/dir/register`" - there shouldn't be any "redirect" in your first scenario? Presumably you just mean that is the URL requested?